# KIE Server fails to execute rules after certain period of time

Tags: java, drools, kie, kie-server

I installed the new version of Drools Rule Engine (7.36) on a Local server
I've deployed the KIE Workbench and KIE Server on a localhost Tomcat 8
(I'm currently using Workbench 7.11 as the newer versions didn't have a **webc** version for Tomcat deployment)

I've managed to configure the server, and deploy a Rule Project. Its runtime strategy is set as *PER REQUEST*, as its KieSessions are set as *stateless* in kmodule.xml

Then I wrote a client to call this server and it's working ok for a few minutes. After that (which I think, they'll be 10 minutes) every other request, throws an ClassCastException, no matter what.
If I restart the deployment unit, it works again for another 10 minutes.

This is the Exception:

```
20-Apr-2020 17:29:49.205 GRAVE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.kie.server.services.drools.DroolsKieContainerCommandServiceImpl.callContainer Error calling container 'PruebaDrools'
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to org.kie.api.command.Command
            at org.kie.server.services.drools.DroolsKieContainerCommandServiceImpl.callContainer(DroolsKieContainerCommandServiceImpl.java:60)
            at org.kie.server.remote.rest.drools.CommandResource.manageContainer(CommandResource.java:91)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:140)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:509)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:399)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:363)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:365)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:337)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:310)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:443)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:233)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:139)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:142)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:219)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.kie.server.services.impl.security.web.CaptureHttpRequestFilter.doFilter(CaptureHttpRequestFilter.java:42)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:668)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
            at org.kie.integration.tomcat.JACCValve.invoke(JACCValve.java:113)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1623)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is my Client:

```
public class MyConfigurationObject {

private static final String URL = "http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server";
private static final String USER = "kieserver";
private static final String PASSWORD = "kieserver1!";

private static final String CONTAINER_ID = "PruebaDrools";
private static final String SESSION_ID = "ksession-dtables";

private static Marshaller xStreamXml;
private static KieServicesConfiguration conf;
private static KieServicesClient client;
private static RuleServicesClient ruleClient;


public static void initialize() {

    conf = KieServicesFactory.newRestConfiguration(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
    conf.setMarshallingFormat(MarshallingFormat.JSON);

    Set<Class<?>> allClasses = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    allClasses.add(MyClass.class);
    conf.addExtraClasses(allClasses);

    xStreamXml = MarshallerFactory.getMarshaller(allClasses, MarshallingFormat.JSON, MyConfigurationObject.class.getClassLoader());


    client  = KieServicesFactory.newKieServicesClient(conf);
    ruleClient = client.getServicesClient(RuleServicesClient.class);
}

//Para la version 7.36
public static void sendCommands() {
    BatchExecutionCommandImpl command = new BatchExecutionCommandImpl(new ArrayList<Command>());
    command.setLookup(SESSION_ID);

    InsertObjectCommand insertObjectCommand = new InsertObjectCommand("banana");
    FireAllRulesCommand fireAllRulesCommand = new FireAllRulesCommand();

    command.getCommands().add(insertObjectCommand);
    command.getCommands().add(fireAllRulesCommand);

    ServiceResponse<ExecutionResults> response = ruleClient.executeCommandsWithResults(CONTAINER_ID,command);
    System.out.println(response.getResult());
}

//Para la version 7.36
public static void sendCommands(Object[] args) {

    InsertObjectCommand insertObjectCommand = new InsertObjectCommand("enviar");

    InsertElementsCommand insertElementsCommand = new InsertElementsCommand(Arrays.asList(args));
    insertElementsCommand.setOutIdentifier("denuncia");

    FireAllRulesCommand fireAllRulesCommand = new FireAllRulesCommand();
    GetObjectsCommand getObjectsCommand = new GetObjectsCommand();
    getObjectsCommand.setOutIdentifier("denuncia");

    //Dispose session
    DisposeCommand disposeCommand = new DisposeCommand();

    KieCommands commandsFactory = KieServices.Factory.get().getCommands();
    List<Command<?>> commands = new ArrayList<Command<?>>();
    BatchExecutionCommand executionCommand = commandsFactory.newBatchExecution(commands, SESSION_ID);

    commands.add(insertObjectCommand);
    commands.add(insertElementsCommand);
    commands.add(fireAllRulesCommand);
    commands.add(getObjectsCommand);
    commands.add(disposeCommand);



    ServiceResponse<ExecutionResults> response = ruleClient.executeCommandsWithResults(CONTAINER_ID, xStreamXml.marshall(executionCommand));
    System.out.println(xStreamXml.marshall(response.getResult().getValue("denuncia")));
}
```

I use `MyConfigurationObject` in a **main** class, calling its static methods, **initialize()** first and then **sendCommands()** with my Objects as arguments

I found that this Exception is quite general, and it can be caused by many reasons, but the logs won't provide any extra information of what's going on

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try debugging into the method you are invoking and seeing where the exception occurs?

Comment: Though if you look at the source for the class in the stack trace, you can see that [line 60](https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/blob/master/kie-server-parent/kie-server-services/kie-server-services-drools/src/main/java/org/kie/server/services/drools/DroolsKieContainerCommandServiceImpl.java#L60) is an unmarshall command, so my theory is that there is something wrong with your marshaller.